# Does a Backflip

Tags: riddle

> It swims.
> Does a backflip.
> Still swims.

**What is it?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is

> SWIMS

Because

> SWIMS is an Ambigram, when you rotate the capitalized word SWIMS around, you still get SWIMS.

Another word with this property is

> NOON

Comment: Since there are a lot of letter combinations that can be used like this, my colleague and I implemented this exact transformation as a silly cipher for testing a password safe application's cipher plug-in functionality. I'm still kicking myself for not being the one of us that had the idea to name the cipher "up/dn".

Comment: A backflip that only goes 180 degrees is a pretty poor backflip.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica it's either a handstand or a broken neck.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Maybe a blackflop?

Answer (score 11):

It might be just

> The word SWIMS

Reasoning

> If you turned the word SWIMS through 180 degrees (do a backflip) it remains the same.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqCpjFMvz-k#t=65

Answer (score 11):

> The word swims, since it has 180 degree rotational symmetry!

Comment: Wow, we got 3 answers all within one minute!

Comment: Ha yes, so weird!